# Detecting line closest to the mouse pointer with interrupted lines

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have built a d3 line chart with 3 lines and a line has been highlighted, when the user has been moving the mouse over the line. It turns out, that it is very difficult to select the lines this way. So I tried to write a code to detect the line, that is closest to the mouse (in vertical dimension). This works fine:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7CD1KtqUJVnUF4KgFmUm?p=preview

My problem now is, that this doesn't work this way, if the lines are "interrupted" at the beginning.

http://plnkr.co/edit/0as4QOYVYO0dhZIjGx86?p=preview

I added a `defined()` call to the line function:

```
var line0 = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("cardinal")
    .x(function(d,i) {return x(i);})
    .y(function(d) {return y(d);});
var line1 = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("cardinal")
    .x(function(d,i) {return x(i);})
    .y(function(d) {return y(d);})
    .defined(function (d,i) {return i > 1;});   // <- Here ...
var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("cardinal")
    .x(function(d,i) {return x(i);})
    .y(function(d) {return y(d);})
    .defined(function (d,i) {return i > 3;});   // <- and here.
```

The same problem, if the lines are starting with different x values, what I have simulated a bit hackish here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/hOtXOmQapYsuYgf9HkD3?p=preview

The lines, I am showing connect measurement values and if measurements are missing, the lines are interrupted. So these interruptions can be everywhere. Do you know a solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here my final solution without hidden lines:

http://plnkr.co/edit/mGIUnwNNZxtuyobAWs0P?p=preview

The data format is a bit specific, but that could easily adapted.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you draw pairs of lines, the first would be the one you're drawing now but with pointer-events:none and then the second (with the same co-ordinates) would be visibility:hidden but with a stroke and a reasonable stroke-width so it's easy to select.

When the user mouses over the hidden line you can process that just as if he's moused over the visible line.

Comment: Do you mean to use a ordinary onmouseover for the thick line? The problem there would be to select a line, if two lines are very close to each other. Then one hidden line would cover the other. I didn't knew, that hidden elements are firing onmouseover events. Are you sure, they do?

Comment: Here is a quick test: http://plnkr.co/edit/okFsGRukSp3lV0uchNlN?p=preview Is there anything wrong? But anyways: I could draw thick white lines behind all "visible" lines, but that would not solve the problem, that the wrong line would be selected, if the lines are very close together.

Comment: What's wrong is that that's not an SVG test, that's html that is. The rulz is different. If the wrong line is selected then the user just has to move the cursor so that the right line is selected. Change the colour on selection to provide feedback.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you! But "moving the curser" is no solution for me. Also, there could be many lines very close together and if there is a line A at y=0, a line B at y=1 and a line C at y=2 and B would have the lowest z-index, you would not be able to select B, if the "mouseoverdetectionlines" are thicker than 1 y unit. I think this could be improved a bit in combining it with a mouseover of the visible lines, but ... this is nothing, I can present.

Comment: But you gave me an idea. Maybe I can draw two lines. One, that is interrupted (original data) and one invisible, that has no holes and then use the function, that already works, on the invisible, continuous line. Maybe, that could work. I'll try it out.

Comment: Okay, that worked. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18376348/865334

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding one hidden line for each visible line and applying the function shown in the question on the hidden line. I added some points, to ensure, that each hidden line starts at the left of the chart, has no interruption and ends at the end of the chart.

At this image I left the hidden lines visible with lower saturation and marked those extra points. Except for the added start and end points, they are very close to the original points and it seems to work quite well with `basis` and `monotone` interpolation:

[image: extra points]

1. Calculate the lowest and the highest `x` value.
2. Add the extra data records (use shift() and push() to "iterate" over the data) and set `s: true` for each extra point.
3. Copy the line function into two line function (`lineHidden` and `lineVisible`).
4. Add the condition `!record.s` to the `defined()` function of `linieVisible`.
5. Draw a visible and a hidden line for each series by using the two line functions and make the hidden line hidden. Put the lines in two variables: `var hiddenLines = [...], visibleLines = [...]`.
6. Use the function shown in the question on the hidden lines, but make the highlighting on the visible lines.

Next task would be, to not highlight a line, if it is interrupted at the mouse position...

**Edit**

Could solve that by creating an array

```
interruptions = [
    [<x pos left>, <x pos right>, <series id>],
    ...
]
```

The x positions could be calculated with the scale function `x()`.

And in the mouseover I iterate over that array to look up, which lines have interruptions here to only use the other ones.